# PHP: Make dynamic charts from data out of an oracle database in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oracle, dynamic

I have an order from a company for school.
I'm  a trainee and it’s intended that I get data from an Oracle database, and shows in a graph in wordpress.
For the charts I use the tool PHPGraphLIB API.
and to create an PHP environment in Wordpress I use the plugin: 
insert_php
I use this script for the graph in Wordpress:

```
<?php
$graph = new stdclass;
$graph->width = 500;
$graph->height = 350;
$graph->data=array('AL'=>3731, 'MI'=>763, 'NY'=>3245, 'TX'=>4373, 'WA'=>12124, 'WY'=>5535);
$graph->setGradient = array('red', 'maroon');
$graph->setLegend = 'true';
$graph->setLegendTitle = 'Widgets';
$graph->setTitle = 'Widgets Produced Per State';
$graph->setTitleLocation = 'left';

//JSON encode graph object
$encoded = urlencode(json_encode($graph));

//retrieve XML
$target = 'http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/api/?g=' . $encoded .     '&type=xml';
$xml_object =  new SimpleXMLElement($target, NULL, TRUE);

//if there are no errors, display graph
if (empty($xml_object->error)) {
echo $xml_object->imageTag;
}
else {
echo 'There was an error generating the graph: '. $xml_object->error;
}
?>
```

I can not show the graph because I have not 10 reputation points... but anyone can run this script.

But instead of making use of static data I want the data to be automatically extracted from an Oracle database.

This is the part of the database where its all about:

**Table: TBB**

**Column: A**

```
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18,
19,
20,
21,
22,
23,
```

**Column: B**

```
17,6-
18,4-
18,7-
19-
19,4-
19,1-
21,7-
23,7-
22,6-
20,5-
18,8-
18,6-
18,6-
18,3-
18,6-
18,6-
18,6-
```

I want column A on the horizontal line and I want the data in column B in the graph make appear. and in the vertical axis there will be the numbers from 0 to 30, for example.

But the big question is: HOW?

I do have a oci connection to the oracle database with this script:

```
$conn = oci_connect('server', 'password', ‘somewhere’:Port/THEDB);
```

I've tried a few things but it really do not succeed.
I hope someone can help me with this, that would make me very happy:)!

Comment: The data in your database bears no similarity to the data you are manually adding in the graph script at present. Is it a different kind of graph? Where are the US state keys (`NY` etc) in your database data?

Comment: The data in the graph are an example and are just randomly chosen.

I want to view my personal data from the database in a graph.
And if the data is changed in the database, which is then also changed along the graph.
So column A (7, 8, 9 etc.) should come to stand on the site of the US State keys (G, MI NY etc.) Thanks

Comment: Right, so you just need an array of states (which you can hold in code, as at present) and to use those as keys for data in your database. Have you tried reading data from the Oracle connection yet? It seems you are 90% of the way there.

Comment: yes I created a code in Visual Studio and I get the data neatly aligned as output.
So that works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you place in this line of your code the ***array***, the problem should be fixed.

```
$graph->data=array('AL'=>3731, 'MI'=>763, 'NY'=>3245, 'TX'=>4373, 'WA'=>12124, 'WY'=>5535);

$graph->data=array($array);
```

Comment: and how do you make an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you place in this line of your code the array, the problem should be fixed.

```
$graph->data=array('AL'=>3731, 'MI'=>763, 'NY'=>3245, 'TX'=>4373, 'WA'=>12124, 'WY'=>5535);

$graph->data=array($array);
```

I am not gonna tell you how to make that array, because it is your application.

Comment: Is it difficult to make? is it a long script? Do you have a link or something that helps a bit.

Comment: If I look to your code I think it is a long script and it is diificult to make. Sorry I don't have a link but there is a lot of information on the internet I think. Good luck with your script.